# Is there a library for implementing view model decorators ala Draper in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I want "view model decorators" like [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) implements for Rails, in Django.

I already use `get_absolute_url` and variants of it (edit, delete, etc) – which makes reversing common model URLs easier, but now I find myself writing things like this a lot in templates:

```
{% if user has 'accounts.view_user' of article.author %}
    <a href="{{ article.author.get_absolute_url }}" class="fn">
        {{ article.author.name }}
    </a>
{% else %}
    {{ article.author.name }}
{% endif %}
```

Sure would be nice to have something more concise and DRY, like:

```
{{ user.link }}

{{ user.edit_link }}
```

What Draper does is allow you to define that the model passed to the template should be "decorated" i.e. wrapped in a class that supplies extra methods, and optionally proxies everything that doesn't match up to the real model class - separating model-specific templating logic away from data-orientated model methods.

I don't really want to pollute my models to do it.

If I were to do something similar manually, it would involve doing this like this in my view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CapturesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context.update({
        "article": ArticleDecorator(self.object)
    })

    return context
```

And `ArticleDecorator` would define the link methods, and use magic methods to pass any other attr calls to the real `Article` object.

However, doing all of this manually is pretty messy, and the Draper gem would automates things like automatically decorating relationships of decorated models e.g. `ArticleDecorator.comments` would return a list of `CommentDecorator`'s rather than `Comments`.

---

Are there any libraries to automate this kind of model abstraction for views?

Comment: Something like a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)?

Comment: @J0HN no, I'll improve my question with an example

Answer (score 2):

In django, adding specific behaviours to a model without touching the original model is usually done with a ["proxy model"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)